# From a list of words to listed words

Tags: lists

I would like to go from a list of words through a dedicated command, for instance `\listofwords{one word;one longer word;word and word}` to the expanded list of the same words, ie:

```
\begin{list}{}
\item one word
\item one longer word
\item word and word
\end{list}
```

and the initial list could store more (or less) semicolon-separated words.

**Edit** The following may be more challenging: how to go from two different lists, `\listofwords{word;wordd;worddd}` and `\listofterms{term;termm;termmm}` to

```
\begin{list}{}{}
\item word term
\item wordd termm
\item worddd termmm
\end{list}
```

where `worddd` (or any other of the lists above) could store several space-separated words. Based on the previous answers, I had a look at the `xparse` and `etoolbox` packages but could no find any useful solution :(

Comment: Does it have to use semicolon as the delimiter, or would commas work as well?

Comment: semicolon are preferred because commas could be part of the `words`. Is this a problem?

Comment: @pluton and semicolons can't be part of the words?

Comment: well, no they are not supposed to but `\listofwords{one word}{one longer word}{word and word}` would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides list processing capabilities to suit this requirement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofwords}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\item ##1}% Update how the list items will be processed
  \begin{list}{}{}%
    \@listofwords{#1}% Process items
  \end{list}%
}
\DeclareListParser{\@listofwords}{;}% \@listofwords{<word>;<word>;...}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listofwords{one word;one longer word;word and word}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item one word
\item one longer word
\item word and word
\end{list}
\end{document}​
```

`\DeclareListParser{\@listofwords}{;}` creates a list parser `\@listofwords` that processes its separated by `;`.

Answer (score 11):

This is easy with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listofwords}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}
 {\begin{list}{}{}
  \ProcessList{#1}{\additem}%
  \end{list}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\additem}{m}{\item #1}

\begin{document}
\listofwords{one word;one longer word;word and word}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item one word
\item one longer word
\item word and word
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

The `list` environment is just to show that the output is identical. (Note that `list` takes two arguments.)

[image]

Comment: I am giving points to Werner so that you are not too far ahead :)